# How can you give the python interpreter commands from within a script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting

I wrote a bash script to create a setup file using
`echo '...' > setup.py`
and then in the next line I execute it using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.  I replicated the first part with the write method of file objects in Python, my question is how can I replicate the second part in my Python script?

Comment: Why can't you just run the code in your script instead of piping it into another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems like you're trying to do is not to give the Python interpreter commands, but actually to execute bash/shell commands from within a Python program execution.

When you open a terminal and run:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

What happens is that a new Python process starts up and executes setup.py

Your goal is to do the same thing from a Python script.  The generally accepted way to do this is to use the `subprocess` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Something like

```
subprocess.run(["python", "setup.py", "build_ext", "--inplace"])
```

should work.  Or if you really know what you're doing and you know that the input to the `subprocess.run` call won't ever get exposed to users (and thus hijacked) you could instead use:

```
subprocess.run("python setup.py build_ext --inplace", shell=True)
```

#### EDIT:

Alternatively if you want to dig deep into Python you could go look at how to call setuptools' build_ext command directly from code.  Here's a good start in that direction.
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/setuptools/command/build_ext.py#L83